# Apache camel simple operators contains

Tags: ldap, apache-camel, blueprint

I'm working with apache camel V2.24.3,and I want to check if ${body} contains this 2 strings.

```
 <choice id="ldap_response">
                                <when id="ldap_response_adding">
                                    <simple>${body} contains 'adding' && 'modifying'</simple>
                                </when>
   </choice>
```

this code returns an error:

> 'The identity name must immediately follow the "&" character in the
> entity reference.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<simple>${body} contains 'adding' and ${body} contains 'modifying'</simple>`